# Jenkins with Tomcat 7.x and maven is not deploying remote

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, tomcat, jenkins

Here is the error:

> ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
>   org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [C:\Users\Administrator.jenkins\jobs...[PATH OF THE WAR]
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:193)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
>       at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1030)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
>       at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>       at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:534)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
>       ... 16 more
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>       at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:211)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:851)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:534)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:686)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:699)
>       at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:174)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:73)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:914)
>       at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:887)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
>       at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
>       at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:757)
>       at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1030)
>       at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:706)
>       at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1703)
>       at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:519)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Have you read the stacktrace ?

Comment: Yes I have read

Comment: connection refuse to connect but not sure why?? Can it be something db related also. I have db on aws for this war

Comment: obviously not... the db is not related cause the exception is in the context of Tomcat which means the connection to Tomcat (deployer) does not work....

Comment: Oh okey let me figure out that then.. Thanks for the prompt reply :-)